# Paramiko - ssh to console server, having to hit return for script to continue

Tags: python, paramiko

Just using my first paramiko script, we have an opengear console server, so I'm trying to automate setup of any device we plug into it.

The open gear listens for ssh connections on ports, for example a device in port 1 would be 3001. I am connecting to a device on port 8, which works and my script runs, but for some reason, after I get the "Interactive SSH session established" message, I need to hit return on the session to make it run (so I have a ssh session and the script does too, its shared).

It just waits there until I hit return, I've tried sending returns as you can see but they don't work, only a manual return works, which is odd because technically they are the same thing?

```
import paramiko
import time

def disable_paging(remote_conn):
    '''Disable paging on a Cisco router'''
    remote_conn.send("terminal length 0\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    # Clear the buffer on the screen
    output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # VARIABLES THAT NEED CHANGED
    ip = '192.168.1.10'
    username = 'root'
    password = 'XXXXXX'
    port = 3008

    # Create instance of SSHClient object
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Automatically add untrusted hosts (make sure okay for security policy in your environment)
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
         paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    # initiate SSH connection
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password,port=port, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    print "SSH connection established to %s" % ip

    # Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    print "Interactive SSH session established"
    time.sleep(1)
    remote_conn.send("\n")

    # Strip the initial router prompt
    #output = remote_conn.recv(1000)

    # See what we have
    #print output

    # Turn off paging
    #disable_paging(remote_conn)

    # clear any config sessions
    is_global = remote_conn.recv(1024)
    if ")#" in is_global:
        remote_conn.send("end\n")
        time.sleep(2)
    # if not in enable mode go to enable mode
    is_enable = remote_conn.recv(1024)
    if ">" in is_enable:
        remote_conn.send("enable\n")
        time.sleep(1)
    remote_conn.send("conf t\n")
    remote_conn.send("int g0/0/1\n")
    remote_conn.send("ip address 192.168.1.21 255.255.255.0\n")
    remote_conn.send("no shut\n")
    remote_conn.send("end\n")
    # Wait for the command to complete
    time.sleep(2)
    remote_conn.send("ping 192.168.1.1\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
    print output
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ive found another module (netmiko) which does exactly what i want and does all these checks. ive since abandoned trying to do it myself when someone else has already done it better.

use Netmiko! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and saw that

```
is_global = remote_conn.recv(1024)
```

hangs,
Are you sure '192.168.1.10' sends somthing to be received ?
Try setting a timeout

```
remote_conn.settimeout(3)
```

3 seconds for example, do it after this line:

```
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
```

this way the recv func does not hang and continues when timeout expires

works for me

Answer (score 0):

first send some command "ls -ltr\n" and then call sleep

```
remote_conn.send("ls -ltr\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running your command in a debugger and find out what line is waiting for input. You might also try sending \r or \r\n instead if just \n. Remember the enter key is really ^M

You might also try turning on detailed logging.

```
import logging
# ...
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: logging is not defined. do i need to add something? also ive ntoiced that the first carrige return works, i watch the console and see it, then it does the pause until i hit a further return the script then runs

Comment: I added the import statement.

Comment: No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"